# How to create decorators that run forever?

Tags: python, python-requests, decorator

I was looking for the possible solutions to "How to create decorators in python **that run forever**?" and i never found it **the way i need**.

```py
import downloader
import requests

app = downloader()

@app.on_download(multipart=False)
def do(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open('file.ext','w+') as f:
        f.write(r.text)
        
@app.on_download(multipart=True)
def do(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open('file.ext','w+') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(10240):
            f.write(chunk)
        
@app.run()
```

The download items will be found at "downloads.json" in script directory:

```json
[
    "http://www.example.com/path/file.ext"
]
```

Comment: Why do you *need* a decorator? Why not just iterate `do()` over a list of downloads?

Comment: You haven't described **the way i need**, so it's hard to say… Note that decorators only run when they are applied to a function.

Comment: @martineau The code on top is the usage. how can i create decorator and then i use it this way?

Comment: Sorry, that code is not enough of a description. What's supposed to happen that isn't? What's a `downloader()`?

Comment: @RolandSmith how to iterate ```do()```?

Comment: @martineau It is main downloader class which inform me when new item add to downloads.json

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with that module.

Answer (score 0):

First, read the URL's from `downloads.json`, assuming it is a simple list:

```
import json

with open("downloads.json") as df:
    downloads = json.load(df)
```

From your example, the URL's end in a filename, so we will split that off to create the filename:

```
Python 3.9.9 (main, Dec 11 2021, 14:34:11) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> url = "http://www.example.com/path/file.ext"
>>> url.rsplit("/", maxsplit=1)[1]
'file.ext'
```

Then simply download the URL's in turn, and save the contents in a file.

```
import requests

for url in downloads:
    r = requests.get(url)
    filename = url.rsplit("/", maxsplit=1)[1]
    with open(filename,'w+') as outf:
        outf.write(r.text)
```